# Find two string in same line and then replace using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am doing a find and replace using `sed` in a `bash` script. I want to search each file for words with `files` and `no`. If both the words are present in the same line then replace `red` with `green` else do nothing

```
sed -i -e '/files|no s/red/green' $file
```

But I am unable to do so. I am not receiving any error and the file doesn't get updated.

What am I doing wrong here or what is the correct way of achieving my result

Comment: `|` means it matches either one, it doesn't have to be both

Comment: Can the words be in any order on the line?

Comment: @Barmar They can be in any order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/files|no/` means to match lines with either `files` or `no`, it doesn't require both words on the same line.

To match the words in either order, use `/files.*no|no.*files/`.

```
sed -i -r -e '/files.*no|no.*files/s/red/green/' "$file"
```

Notice that you need another `/` at the end of the pattern, before `s`, and the `s` operation requires `/` at the end of the replacement.

And you need the `-r` option to make `sed` use extended regexp; otherwise you have to use `\|` instead of just `|`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/files/{/no/s/red/green/}' file
```

or:

```
sed '/files/!b;/no/s/red/green/' file
```

This method allows for easy extension e.g. foo, bar and baz:

```
sed '/foo/!b;/bar/!b;/baz/!b;s/red/green/' file
```

or fee, fie, foe and fix:

```
 sed '/fee/!b;/fi/!b;/foe/!b;/fix/!b;s/bacon/cereal/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

An `awk` verison

```
awk '/files/ && /no/ {sub(/red/,"green")} 1' file
```

- `/files/ && /no/` `files` and `no` have to be on the same line, in any order
- `sub(/red/,"green")` replace `red` with `green`.  Use `gsub(/red/,"green")` if there are multiple `red`
- `1` always true, do the default action, print the line.